# Do MVC routes look at subdomains also?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Do/can routes in .net MVC look at subdomains?

i.e. subdomain1.example.com

Answer (score 3):

The route handler which is built into ASP.NET SP1 (Note that it's not just for MVC) doesn't care about the domain name, the only thing it parses is the stuff after the root directory. For example if your route is: `http://www.foo.example.com/site-root/Controller/Action/id?bar=temp` The route handler parses the the stuff which occurs after the site-root/ (Note: your site-root might actually be a "/"). Hope that helps